# Reading stream from infinite loop

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I'm trying out some socket programming in Java for a little project. I've ran into a problem reading an infinite InputStream from an external process. The program goes into an infinite loop.

I suspect that readLine() have to read the stream until EOF.

I've put some print statements and I'm sure that the program reaches the while-loop.

This is my method:

```
    public void run() throws IOException {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime() .exec(exe);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
            dout.writeUTF(" " + line + " yes!");
            dout.flush();
        }

        in.close();
        dout.close();
        s.close();
        ss.close();
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to say what your problem is.

Comment: Thank you! Added that the program goes into an infinite loop

Comment: You won't reach an EOF until the process you're starting in the first line exits. Until then, a call to `readLine` blocks

Comment: What command you are using in Runtime.getRuntime(exec());?

Comment: It's a simple compiled C-program that prints a message in an infinite while-loop

Comment: I know I won't be reaching EOF, since there is none. So I was right about readLine()? That it reads until EOF first

Comment: Correct, it loops until EOF, so if the process prints forever, when would you want your logic to exit? And if you exit your loop, that doesn't kill the process, so what's your intent for stopping the process?

Comment: My intent is to keep reading it. Later on I will figure out a way to connect and disconnect to the socket without ending the process. But for now I just want to keep reading to get that working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @codeflush.dev mentioned the stream does not reach EOF and readLine is therefore not a viable option.